# .net asynchronus programming guide

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

i`v been studing about async progrmaming in .net today
and what i understood is that this code Should NOT create a new thread but i see different 
ThreadId with calling Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Do();
        Console.WriteLine("Main {0}",Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        Thread.Sleep(400);
    }

    private static async void Do()
    {
        Task<string> task = new StreamReader(@"D:\a.txt").ReadLineAsync();
        string result = await task;
        Console.WriteLine("DO {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
```

thanks everyone for reading this..

Comment: This article had a good explanation: http://www.gamlor.info/wordpress/2010/10/c-5-0-async-feature-be-aware-of-the-synchronization-context/

Comment: Thanks for linking to the article.

Comment: wow! greate.. you saved my mind dude

Comment: @user2924454: I have an [`async` intro on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that you may find helpful; I tried to make it an intro that covers everything you *need* to know in a single post, with detailed followup links at the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your getting different thread ids is that you have created a console app. On a UI app there is a special `SynchronizationContext` saying that the callbacks should be on the UI thread. Console apps don't have this synchronization context as the console methods are thread safe so don.t need to be called on the main thread. This means that an async call on the the main thread behaves the same as on any user created threads would which is to fire callbacks to the thread pool as your seeing.

Comment: Is a console app so it behaves like a user created thread would in a UI app.